# Add CultureInfo to DisplayFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, formatting

I'm working in a multi-culture application that needs to display dates and currencies in different culture formats on the same view.  Normally I use the `DisplayFormatAttribute` with `DataFormatString` and let `DisplayFor` automatically format for me. In this case, that causes all my dates/currencies to show in only one culture.

Is there a way to add culture info to `DisplayFor`?

Comment: AFAIK, not directly but you could create display templates for each culture and format the value in the template, then use `DisplayFor(m => m.MyDate, "FrenchDate")`

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenMuecke pointed out, I can specify the display template.

I'm going to use a `UIHint` on the model properties with an associated display template.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute
    : DisplayFormatAttribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private Type LocalizedResourceType { get; set; }
    public string LocalizedDataFormatString { get; set; }
    public string LocalizedNullDisplayText { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        if (LocalizedResourceType != null)
        {
            var resource = new ResourceManager(LocalizedResourceType);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocalizedDataFormatString) != true)
            {
                DataFormatString = resource.GetString(LocalizedDataFormatString);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocalizedNullDisplayText) != true)
            {
                NullDisplayText = resource.GetString(LocalizedNullDisplayText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [LocalizedDisplayFormat(LocalizedDataFormatString = "Resource_Key_Here", LocalizedResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```